# python groupby per second not functionning

Tags: python, datetime, group-by

have to admit that it's a great moment for me :I finally post a question in stackoverflow after spending so much time reading the forum.

Have csv file with a list of trade orders done during a day, with sometimes more than 100 lines in 1 second

```
data1

>CO1 Comdty              A      B       C   D       
>2017-08-10 00:00:00    TRADE   52.70   1   NaN
>2017-08-10 00:00:00    TRADE   52.70   1   NaN
>2017-08-10 00:00:00    TRADE   52.70   1   NaN
>2017-08-10 00:00:00    TRADE   52.84   1   NaN
........................
>2017-08-10 00:00:02    TRADE   52.90   1   NaN
>2017-08-10 00:00:02    TRADE   52.92   1   NaN
```

Index is a Datetime object as per following :

```
DatetimeIndex(['2017-08-10 00:00:00', '2017-08-10 00:00:00',
           '2017-08-10 00:00:00', '2017-08-10 00:00:00',
           '2017-08-10 00:00:00', '2017-08-10 00:00:00',
           '2017-08-10 00:00:00', '2017-08-10 00:00:00',
           '2017-08-10 00:00:00', '2017-08-10 00:00:00',
           ...
           '2017-08-21 23:58:00', '2017-08-21 23:58:00',
           '2017-08-21 23:58:00', '2017-08-21 23:58:00',
           '2017-08-21 23:58:00', '2017-08-21 23:58:00',
           '2017-08-21 23:58:00', '2017-08-21 23:58:00',
           '2017-08-21 23:58:00', '2017-08-21 23:58:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=u'CO1 Comdty', length=1005276, freq=None)
```

I use groupby function to take the mean for each second

```
dataG1 = data1.groupby([data1.index.month,data1.index.day,data1.index.hour,data1.index.minute,data1.index.second])['B'].mean()
```

The result is giving me a MultiIndex Serie grouped by minute at Second 0

```
8  10  0   0   0    52.702941
           1   0    52.700000
           2   0    52.704333
           3   0    52.690000
           4   0    52.689691
           5   0    52.690000
           7   0    52.700000
           8   0    52.700000
           9   0    52.704444
           10  0    52.710652
           ....................
```

So as you can see the last column with price is given every Minute ( and second 0 ) and I want average every Second ! (columns are  Month / Day / Hour / Minute / Second )

When I try to group by Month, Day, Hour and Minute it is calculating correctly.

Couldn't find solution anywhere, can someone help ?

Thanks!

To answer to Parfait's comments :

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Yes you can download csv file with following link :

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/99bac8dbdba2a95aad347500b70da96e20170917073900/a12761f7bca3bd4f40efeaf76015787c20170917073900/31f902

```
data1 = pd.read_csv('data1.csv',sep=',', parse_dates=[0], index_col=0,infer_datetime_format=True)

dataG1 = data1.groupby([data1.index.month,data1.index.day,data1.index.hour, data1.index.minute,data1.index.second])['B'].mean()

dataG1
```

Then you should see the same result.

Thks again !

Comment: Your index looks to have all zero seconds with omission. Without a full [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we cannot help further.

Comment: Thanks, I added a link in original message to download csv file.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the CSV file and it appears it's simply not in your data:

```
CO1 Comdty  A   B   C   D   
08-10-17 00:00  TRADE   52.7    1       
08-10-17 00:00  TRADE   52.7    1       
08-10-17 00:00  TRADE   52.7    1       
08-10-17 00:00  TRADE   52.7    1       
... 
08-10-17 00:01  TRADE   52.7    1       
08-10-17 00:01  TRADE   52.7    1       
08-10-17 00:01  TRADE   52.7    1
```

You'd have to reindex your data if you really want to group by seconds. However, be careful with that because you don't seem to have an equal number of samples per minute so I assume you have an arbitrary interval that gives you the next sample.

---

This is how your reindexing could look like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('data1.csv')

data_end = data1[::-1].index[0] + pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)
tmp = data1.groupby(data1.index.minute)['B'].count()
tmp = tmp.append(pd.DataFrame([0], index=[data_end.minute]))[0]

indices = list()
start = data1.index[0]

for s, e in zip(tmp[:len(tmp)-1].iteritems(), tmp[1:].iteritems()):  
    smin, sint = s
    emin, eint = e

    start = data1.index[0] + pd.Timedelta(minutes=smin)
    end = data1.index[0] + pd.Timedelta(minutes=emin)

    indices.append( pd.to_datetime(np.linspace(start.value, end.value, sint)) )
    start = end

data1.index = np.hstack(indices)
```

This will simply reindex all samples by distributing them equally for each minute. However this is a big assumption and you have to know whether this is a valid thing to do or not.

```
8  10  0  0  0     52.700
             1     52.700
             3     52.700
             5     52.700
             7     52.700
             9     52.700
             10    52.700
             12    52.700
             14    52.710
             16    52.710
             18    52.700
             20    52.710
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, it is not a convenient solution for me as I will always have different sample size per minute. In addition I need to have the average price on the exact second.

I realized information was missing in the csv file; because when I pasted data as "datetime" from excel into csv it was losing the decimal part of the index where are the seconds, milliseconds etc.

Found solution by pasting value as float value and then convert it to datetime using following transformation:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('data1.csv')

data1.index = pd.to_datetime(1000000000*86400*(data1.index-25569))

dataG1 = data1.groupby([data1.index.month,data1.index.day,data1.index.hour, 
data1.index.minute,data1.index.second])['B'].mean()

dataG1 = dataG1.reset_index()

dataG1


 8  10  0   0   0     52.701818
                1     52.710000
                8     52.700000
                10    52.700000
                13    52.703889
                59    52.700000
            1   59    52.700000
            2   5     52.708462
                7     52.710000
                15    52.700000
  .............................
```

I have slightly different average price though... for example the first row at 8/10/0/0 and second 0 averages 52.701818 instead of 52.70231

And I'm not convinced by my solution either, I would like to have same interval as per your example and keep same value when it is missing. Keen to hear if you have better idea.

[https://wetransfer.com/downloads/df4f8526ddc711e08f556245fac093ac20170918121109/f2928133e8c17a9de98a0460483747c320170918121109/3857ff ][1]

Many thks!